# Keywords arguments in matplotlib radviz

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

I am trying to understand the keyword arguments that can be used in matplotlib radviz. I am using the well-known iris dataset, and the simple code below:

```
import pandas as pd
plt.xkcd()
iris = pd.read_csv("iris.csv")
pd.tools.plotting.radviz(iris, "name")
```

Generating the following chart:[image: radviz plot]

How can I setup the dimensions (x, y) and the title of the chart? How can I specify the placement of the legend? What other arguments (if any) can be used with radviz?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

all the pandas plotting tools take an `ax` argument, you can make the axis and pass to the plotting function:

```
fig = plt.figure( )
ax = fig.add_axes( [.05, .05, .9, .9], title='whatever title' )
pd.tools.plotting.radviz( iris, 'name', ax=ax )
```

then if you need to change the legend, you may do:

```
ax.legend( loc='center right', fontsize='medium' )
```

or change the title:

```
ax.set_title( 'new title' )
```

alternatively, i believe the plotting tools return the axis after plotting, so you may do

```
ax = pd.tools.plotting.radviz( iris, 'name')
```

and check `dir( ax )` for some of the functionality available.

```
with plt.xkcd( ):
    ax = pd.tools.plotting.radviz(df, 'Name')
    ax.legend( loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1),
               fontsize='medium', fancybox=True, ncol=3 )
    ax.set_xlim( -1.6, 1.6, emit=True, auto=False )
    ax.set_title( 'iris - radviz', loc='right' )
```

[image: iris]